# Table error - black band inside the fields on toprule

Tags: tables

[image: table error]

[image: same table without error]

I need a help with a table attached in the pictures above. I put this table in a document composed of several chapters. 
When I compile the single chapter that include the table, i have no error and the table is correctly displayed.
When I compile the entire document whit all the chapters, at the page that contains the table, it appears whit a black band that cover the first field on toprule.

I controlled the code and it is the same. I cannot understand what is wrong.

I put the example code below even if the proble seems to be on the entire document

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{booktabs} 
\usepackage[table]{xcolor} 

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[]\footnotesize
\caption{\#messaggi scambiati a livello RRC nell'arco di 24h in condizione di standby}
%\label{tab:10}
\centering
\medskip
\begin{tabular}{lr}
\toprule
Messaggio & n. \\ 
\midrule
\texttt{RRC CONNECTION REQUEST} & 140 \\
\rowcolor{gray!10}
\texttt{SERVICE REQUEST} & 136 \\
\rowcolor{white}
\texttt{RADIO BEARER SETUP} & 109 \\
\rowcolor{gray!10}
\texttt{SIGNALLING CONNECTION RELEASE INDICATION} & 104 \\
\rowcolor{white}
 & \\
Totale & 4803 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}


\end{document}
```

Comment: Hi, hard to tell without any code. The safest way to isolate the cause is to prepare a [minimal working example](http://theoval.cmp.uea.ac.uk/~nlct/latex/minexample/index.html). That gives us code to test and provide a solution.

Comment: I suspect some redefinition with `\def` or `\renewcommand`. Did you do something to `\heavyrulewidth`?

Comment: I entered the code from the table

Comment: @egreg: No, I have not used redefinitions

Comment: How do you include the chapters?

Comment: @KeksDose:  I made a main file where I put the command like this:  \include{Capitoli/09_prove_di_laboratorio}  ecc. for all chapters

Comment: Does the log file contain error or warning messages in regard to the table, if you compile the whole document? Besides that, does the heavy rule still appear, if you ommit \rowcolor?

Comment: @KeksDose: I followed  your suggestion about the command \rowcolor. I removed all the single command \rowcolor and I put after \begin{table} the command:  \rowcolors{1}{white}{gray!10}, and seems to be solved. the black band is gone

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, this seems to bee the solution: Replace the `\rowcolor{}` commands with a single `\rowcolors{1}{white}{gray!10}` for each tabular.